# CSS for gradient overlay from only left side

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm attempting to show a white gradient overlay from just the left side. A liner gradient, from left to right. Where only the left side is white and the right side is transparent. Is this possible with css?

Comment: you should show something you tried n offcourse its possible

Comment: Of course this is possible. Just keep in mind that the background-color of the underlaying element needs to be set to something else than white to actually see it. You can't make your monitor transparent after all ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

doing this, you are setting white-transparent gradient color in your page from left to right

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this one.

```css
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.9) 72%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.78) 100%);

background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(72%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.78)));

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.9) 72%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.78) 100%);

background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.9) 72%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.78) 100%);

background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.9) 72%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.78) 100%);

background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.9) 72%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0.78) 100%);

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in CSS, see this code snippet for example :

```css
body {
  background-color: #9999ff;
}

.bg-demo {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-demo">
  <p>Don't mind me I'm just a very long text, like veeeery long ! I know I'm long right ? I know y'all know better my cousin Lorem Ipsum but hey ! Is he that long ? I don't think so ! Like I said, I am so long you probably won't ever find something as long as me.</p>
  <p>So anyways what is like being long ? It is much like being tall except on a much different axis. Also instead of growing up I am basically "longging left", right ? Just in case that wasn't obvious, I just did a joke, a short one. Yeah sure, that is quite interesting to have a short joke for a text as long as me</p>
</div
```

My whole `body` has a blue background but my `.bg-demo` div has a linear-gradient starting from the left and going from white to transparent.